# Problem with making relationships using Laravel migrations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have problem with Laravel migrations. I want to make a relationship between two tables but

> I am getting error  General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `eshopper`.`prices` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly
> formed") (SQL: alter table `prices` add constraint `pri ces_product_id_foreign` foreign key (`product_id`) references
> `products` (`id`) .

Here is my code. Tables are prices and products.

Prices

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->float('amount');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->index();

            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Products

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("title",100);
            $table->text("description");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

[image]

**NOTE**: In my migrations products table is under prices table, I know that the first created table is prices than products and that is error.
My question is do I have to put products frst or I can keep same layout(prices first, than products) and change something in code?

Comment: you can't reference a table that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

it happens because the `product_id` field type is different from the `id` field in the products table, try this in the products migration file:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id', true); // true here means it's auto incremental
        $table->string("title",100);
        $table->text("description");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: No, still same thing

Comment: are you sure the `products` table migration file is before `prices`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the constraints inside the migration file of `price` you can put it inside the migration file of `products`. Since it will create the `prices` table first before the `products` the constraints will not be created because the `products` table is not yet created.

```
/**
* This is the prices table
*
* it depends in you if you want to define the column here directly without its constraints
* the commented column is optional
*/
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->float('amount');
        //$table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string("title",100);
        $table->text("description");
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    // you can define your constraints here
    Schema::table('prices', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('product_id')
            ->constrained('products')
            ->cascadeOnDelete()
            ->cascadeOnUpdate();

        // if you uncomment the column commented on the prices table instead of the one at above you can use this instead
        $table->foreign('product_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('products')
            ->cascadeOnDelete()
            ->cascadeOnUpdate();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you MUST put `products` first before `prices`. If the whole code is still in development and have yet to get deployed, then the easiest solution is to rename the `products` table migration so that it has older timestamp than the `prices` migration has.